# Symfony 3 login by array of phones

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

Good Day! I want to login my users and it's a trivial task. But issue is checking user by array of values!

For example I have entity user and phone. User have many phones. So I need to login user by all of phones which it has. How can I do it using default tool of security bundle?

I didn't find any question like my one and read all documentation about security in Symfony. The only thing which I thought to do is creating custom provider. But I don't think it solves my problem.

Any ides, dear symfoners? :)

Comment: If I understand, you will use the phone id instead of username? so one user can authenticated with many phone ID

Comment: U need to write a custom auth provedier (like in this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) and authenticate your users with new UsernamePasswordToken (http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set a security provider in **security.yml**

```
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
...

    providers:
        my_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
...
```

Then your entity `AppBundle:User` should implements the interface `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` and have a custom repository for Example `UserRepository` that implements the interface `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface`.
Your `UserRepository` class should look like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{

 /**
  * Loads the user for the given username.
  *
  * This method must return null if the user is not found.
  *
  * @param string $username The username
  * @return null|Utilisateur
  * @throws \Exception
  */
  public function loadUserByUsername($username)
  {
    //Here you write a custom query to retrive the user base on the fields you require. 
    // Here I have used username, email and phone number
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')
        ->leftJoin('u.phones', 'p')
        ->where('u.username = :username or u.email= :email or p.phoneNumber= :phone')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->setParameter('phone ', $username)
        ->getQuery();
    try {
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active user AppBundle:User object identified by "%s".', $username), 0, $e);
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException $ex) {
        throw new \Exception("The user you provided is not unique");
    }
    return $user;
  }
}
```

Your `AppByndle:User` entity class should look like this:

```
<?php


  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

  /**
   * User
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="user")
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Dao\UserRepository")
 */
 class User implements UserInterface
 {
  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=254, nullable=false, unique=true)
    */
    private $username;

    ....
    ....

  }
```

Comment: All good except one: what need to point in getUsername() method for return?
And the second question: what I have to do if I don't have column username? For example, just "name"?

Comment: The field username is not mandatory but the method getUsername() is. This method is ussed to retrieve the login of the user.  In your case, you can implements it to return one of the phones numbers of the user.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to ask then: where the getUsername() used by Security bundle? Is it has important role and particularly what role? You wrote that it can return one the phone. So what phone? That took part in logining? Tell me more details please or maybe some link, which describe this. Many thanks.

Comment: The **getUsername()** method is part of the **UserInterface** i talked about. You can follow those links to learn more http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html and http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html. Hope this help.

Comment: I forgot to say "Many thanks", because I decided my issue! ;)